# Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 gets aborted from 17.10

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 18.04

Upgrading to ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10 giving this error

[image]

Comment: NO its not working for me @karel

Comment: I would rerun the upgrade again and hopefully the programs download properly this time.